# Deducing type for overloaded functions - currying

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, currying, combinatory-logic

Given a callable object ( a function ) `a`, and an argument `b` ( or a series of arguments ), I would like to deduce the type returned from `f` considering that `f` is overloaded with multiple signatures.

one of my many attempts is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>
#include <typeinfo>

int foo(uint32_t a) { return ((a + 0) * 2); }

bool foo(std::string a) { return (a.empty()); }

/*template <typename A, typename B> auto bar(A a, B b) -> decltype(a(b)) {
  return (a(b));
}*/

/*template <typename A, typename B> decltype(std::declval<a(b)>()) bar(A a, B b)
{
  return (a(b));
}*/

template <typename A, typename B> void bar(std::function<A(B)> a, B b) {
  std::cout << a(b) << "\n";
}

int main() {

  // the following 2 lines are trivial and they are working as expected
  std::cout << foo(33) << "\n";
  std::cout << typeid(decltype(foo(std::string("nothing")))).name() << "\n";

  std::cout << bar(foo, 33) << "\n";
  //std::cout << bar(foo, std::string("Heinz")) << "\n";

  return (0);
}
```

and 2 templates options are commented out and included in the previous code.

I'm using `declval result_of auto decltype` without any luck.

How does the overloading resolution process works at compile time ?

If anyone wants to know why I'm trying to get creative with this, is that I'm trying to implement some Currying in C++11 in a workable/neat way.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you're asking, do you mean: How do I infer the return type f() given the arguments?

Comment: What's wrong with `decltype(f(b))`?

Comment: Well, you already mentioned result_of in your question, so your answering my question positively puzzles me :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you can't easily create a function object from an overload set: when you state `foo` or `&foo` (the function decays into a function pointer in most case, I think) you don't get an object but you get an overload set. You can tell the compiler which overload you want by either calling it or providing its signature. As far as I can tell, you don't want either.

The only approach I'm aware of is to turn your function into an actual function object which makes the problem go away:

```
struct foo_object
{
    template <typename... Args>
    auto operator()(Args&&... args) -> decltype(foo(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) {
        return foo(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};
```

With that wrapper which is unfortunately needed for each name, you can trivially deduce the return type, e.g.:

```
template <typename Func, typename... Args>
auto bar(Func func, Args&&... args) -> decltype(func(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) {
    // do something interesting
    return func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main() {
    bar(foo_object(), 17);
    bar(foo_object(), "hello");
}
```

It doesn't quite solve the problem of dealing with overload sets but it gets reasonably close. I experimented with this idea, essentially also for the purpose of currying in the context of an improved system of standard library algorithms and I'm leaning towards the algorithms actually being function objects rather than functions (this is desirable for various other reasons, too; e.g., you don't need to faff about when you want to customize on algorithm with another one).

Comment: so `foo_object` acts like a proxy just like when you build a new object with some perfect forwarding ? EDIT: plus the obvious use of `decltype` for the deduction of the type

Comment: @user2485710: `foo_object` is essentially something which allows the code to name an overload set: the type `foo_object` is something which can be named and an object of it can be created without, yet, knowing which overload is being chosen. Once the arguments are available the compiler will then work out the overload resolution. Admittedly, it is possible to construct cases where different overloads can be found...

Comment: my point is that, to simplify the concept, in C++ 11 there are always this new techniques that are relying on basically the difference between time of `Instantiation` and the time when the compiler completes the substitution of the arguments, sometimes with the help of some reference collapsing rule, in a language like Haskell is so simple to think about a type that in reality the templates in C++ do not let you abstract a type, they are just placeholders for something that needs an "immediate" substitution .

Comment: @user2485710: If Haskell is superior, program Haskell! C++ is not Haskell and the legacy C++ has couldn't be avoided by learning from Haskell, e.g., because C++ is a couple of years older (at least 5 years) and built on top of legacy right from the start in the form the another 10 years older C. The key abstraction C++ is missing to avoid the need of the auxiliary class is an overload set which could be implemented exactly as this auxiliary class. There was certainly talk about adding it but I couldn't locate a proposal with a quick search.

Comment: well, I would like to have another kind of type system, the only problem is that I discovered that Haskell is a really closed environment and it can't be easily bonded with any language, and it's probably supposed to work on its own anyway. Out of curiosity, are you implicitly mentioning the C++ 14 "concepts".

Answer (score 3):

If foo is overloaded, you need to use the following:

```
#include <type_traits>

int foo(int);
float foo(float);

int main() {
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(foo(std::declval<int>())), int>::value, "Nope.");
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(foo(std::declval<float>())), float>::value, "Nope2.");
}
```

If it's not, then this will suffice:

```
#include <type_traits>
bool bar(int);

int main() {
    static_assert(std::is_same<std::result_of<decltype(bar)&(int)>::type, bool>::value, "Nope3.");
}
```

Yes, it is verbose because you're trying to explicitly extract what implicit ad-hoc overloading does for you.

Comment: way too complicated and verbose ... it basically nullifies my goal to make this more "functional" .

Answer (score 2):

This is actually already implemented for you [`std::result_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of). Here is a possible implementation

```
template<class>
struct result_of;

// C++11 implementation, does not satisfy C++14 requirements
template<class F, class... ArgTypes>
struct result_of<F(ArgTypes...)>
{
    typedef decltype(
                     std::declval<F>()(std::declval<ArgTypes>()...)
                    ) type;
};
```

Comment: I would just like to call another templated function `foo` where `T` is the deduced like `foo<T>()` right inside that template. I'm trying this now ...

Comment: I think the OP has the inverse problem: Picking an overload of `foo` based on the existence of a result-of type.

Comment: @KerrekSB so result_of with enable_if then

Comment: @KerrekSB the only thing is in the comments right below his question implying this is what he wants

Comment: @aaronman: I'm thinking "non-deducible context", but please have a go at it.

Comment: @aaronman or it's me or it's not `result_of` that I need http://pastebin.com/Smckyt7q , i tried to call a 3rd function `z` based on what is the deduced type but I just can't get the compiler do the job.

Comment: @KerrekSB what was your idea about, exactly ?

Comment: my main problem is that my compiler keeps complaining about the fact that it's not capable of deducing the type for something so ... simple ...

Comment: @user2485710 what you want might be impossible

Comment: @KerrekSB why ? that's my point, It looks so simple when people thinks in Haskell-like terms, and this semantic is quite simple even for C++, so why this doesn't work, I don't even get how the inference really works under the hood at this point ...